# He cambiado de Eclipse IDE a VS Code y al copiar los proyectos todo da error

Tags: java, visual-studio, vscode

He cambiado de Eclipse a VS Code. He copiado uno de los proyectos que tenia en Eclipse y que estaba funcionando bien, al espacio de trabajo de VS Code. Salen todos los paquetes y clases pero casi todos los tipos salen marcados como que no pueden resolverse como tipos. Pensé que pudiese ser por la versión de JDK pero con otros proyectos no ha pasado. No entiendo donde está el problema o que hice mal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se si esto te servirá, pero [según pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70272479/8838721), borrando la carpeta ".setting", el archivo ".classpath" y el archivo ".project" se resolvió el problema. No me convence, pero puedes probarlo, no pierdes nada.

Comment: Te aconsejo revisar si tienes las extensiones necesarias instaladas para que VSCode soporte el lenguaje Java. Ten en cuenta que no basta una extensión para que reconozca el lenguaje sino que hace falta también una extensión para correrlo, una para debuggear, etc. Busca en la sección "extensiones" aquella de Microsoft que se llama "Extension Pack for Java" - es un paquete de extensiones que trae todo lo que necesitas para trabajar cómodamente con Java. Si sigues teniendo errores deberías chequear que le estás indicando a VSCode correctamente dónde está el JDK que tienes instalado.

Comment: vs code es un editor de texto con potencial de ide, si instalas las extensiones ;)

Comment: @Jaime Menéndez es correcto. Borrando los ficheros que dice funciona correctamente.